# Django IntegrityError-NOT NULL constraint failed: portfolio_myportfolio.holder_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make a portfolio manager app in django. I tried making the holder as a primary key. But in that case, the new entry overlaps the old one. So, I deleted that database and started afresh. Now, when I am trying to add a portfolio with a logged in user, I am getting the error as under:-

IntegrityError-NOT NULL constraint failed: portfolio_myportfolio.holder_id

I also wanted to set my database in such a way that If user adds the quantity of the same stock with same nsecode, it should add up in the previous entry instead of making a new row. In that case, what should be my scenario.

Since, I am very new to python and django, my code is not clean and might have few lines of code, which is un-necessary, any help in removing such errors would be much appreciated.

My Model is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

codes=(tuple of tuples)


class MyPortfolio(models.Model):
    nsecodes = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=codes)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    buyvalue=models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)
    holder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='myportfolio')
# Create your models here.
```

my views. py is :

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import MyPortfolio
from .forms import AddNewForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')
@login_required
def my_portfolio(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        myportfolios=MyPortfolio.objects.filter(holder=request.user)
        return render(request, 'my_portfolio.html',{'myportfolios':myportfolios})
@login_required
def add_new_form(request):
    if  request.user.is_authenticated():
        myportfolios = MyPortfolio.objects.filter(holder=request.user)
        if request.method=="POST":
            form=AddNewForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                myportfolio=form.save()
                myportfolio.nsecodes=form.cleaned.data.get('nsecodes')
                myportfolio.buyvalue = form.cleaned.data.get('buyvalue')
                myportfolio.quantity = form.cleaned.data.get('quantity')
                myportfolio.holder=request.user
                myportfolio.save()
                return redirect('my_portfolio')
        else:
            form=AddNewForm()

        return render(request,'add_new.html',{'form':form,'myportfolios':myportfolios})
```

my forms.py is as under:-

```
class AddNewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    nsecodes=forms.ChoiceField(choices=codes, required=True)
    quantity=forms.IntegerField(min_value=1,required=True)
    buyvalue=forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,required=True,min_value=.01)

    class Meta:
        model=MyPortfolio
        fields=['nsecodes','quantity','buyvalue']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are saving the data before assigning the foreign key id

try this

```
       if form.is_valid():
            myportfolio=form.save(commit=False)
            myportfolio.holder=request.user
            myportfolio.save()
            return redirect('my_portfolio')
```

Comment: Hi, this helped. Can u help me with the other question, I guess when I am making more than one entry for a same nse codes, it is creating two rows, i want to add it up the value with the old one.

Comment: This didn't make any difference. My question is , say I have entered a data like this :- nsecodes=SBIN, qty=20, value=1000. and thereafter i add again nsecodes=SBIN, qty=40, value=2000. In stead of getting two lines of these entries,  I want one like this SBIN, qty=60, value=3000